# Some resources for the upper (lower) derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, reference-request, book-recommendation

Lately I have been looking a bit into [Perron integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron_integral). This integral is defined using lower and upper derivative:
$$\underline Df(x) =\liminf_{y\to x} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \qquad \overline Df(x)=\limsup_{y\to x} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}.$$
(To be more specific, when defining Perron integral of a given function $g$, we are looking at functions $u$, $v$ such that $\overline Dv \le g \le \underline Du$ and the functions $u$, $v$ are, in some sense, close to each other.)

So far it seems that the text I am reading only develops the properties of the upper/lower derivative that are needed in the proofs of various properties of Perron integral. It would be useful to me to gain a bit more insight into these notions, so that I can understand their usage in connection with this integral a bit better. Moreover, these derivatives seem to be interesting by themselves. Of course, I could simply experiment a bit, try to find upper/lower derivatives of some functions and maybe even discover some of their properties of $\underline Df$  and $\overline Df$ by myself. Still, if there are some goods texts which study them more in detail, it would be nice to know about them.

**TL;DR:** Can you recommend some texts (books, lecture notes) which develop some basic properties of lower and upper derivative? (It would be even better if they have some examples and exercises.)

Comment: See Gordon Russell A., `The Integrals of Lebesgue, Denjoy, Perron, and Henstock` (Graduate Studies in Mathematics, Vol.4), American Mathematical Society (1994), chapter 4.